# Execute js in pdf view

Tags: python, django

I have rendered html as a string which will be returned as a PDF response

```
class ReportFileResponse(FileResponse):

    def __init__(self, report, output_format):
        ....... # queries
        if output_format == 'pdf':
            super(ReportFileResponse, self).__init__(streaming_content=my_pdf_str,
                                                 content_type='application/pdf')
```

The problem is that the string contains some js that definitely needs to be executed (modify some blocks). It works in browser (as html), but does not execute in the PDF response. Are there any way to execute JS code?

I think of using Selenium and to execute JS code. But I how to do that when you need to go to the page. But in my case I can't do that. I can't go to the page, because I have rendered html.

At least I need to make queries like `getElementsByClassName` and have access to attributes

P.S. For the rendering we use django-weasyprint

Comment: This is not possible, only a browser can build up the DOM tree and execute your javascript. Can't you use BeautifulSoup and do this in python? You need to pass your final HTML to weasyprint. Since apparently there's no user interaction involved, why are you manipulating the document in javascript and not directly when creating it?

Comment: @dirkgroten. I rewrote my code with python. BeautifulSoup feels nice. You can make  an answer and I will mark it as solved